# htaccess mod_rewrite. error 404 page not found. Help Fix?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am having issues getting mod_rewrite to work. I have an image sharing site, but currently the image URL given leads to a 404 page. This is because the htaccess is not rewriting the urls correctly (or the code is not paired up to the htaccess file.

URL: http://danielardley.com/imgupl/img-579bad054a164.html

htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?danielardley\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ nohotlink.gif [L]
<Files ~ "\.(php|sql|php3|php4|phtml|pl|py|jsp|asp|htm|shtml|sh|cgi)$">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

the site is hosted on a sub dir of the domain, would that cause an issue?

Comment: Does `http://danielardley.com/imgupl/img-579bad054a164.html` exist?

Comment: no, its making the dynamic url into a pretty url.

So script I am using is here, I have uploaded the same file  and it works for them

http://imgshot.com/img-579d3fce20140.html

Comment: Do you overwrite any wordpress `.htaccess` file that was already there?

Comment: Frankerz, I am not using Wordpress, but WP is installed on the main directory of the domain. Would this cause a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Bro You Neeb Add This Code In hataccess `# BEGIN WordPress <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /index.php [L] </IfModule> # END WordPress` To Delete Index Of To You Website [Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag6nO.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: Thanks. I need to remove that WP tbh.

Comment: Also Change Your wp-login.php location in your file  (http://danielardley.com/portfolio/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdanielardley.com%2Fportfolio%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1)